# jquery- how to define specific variable class for element have multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I have elements and each element have multiple classes, and I want to define each of these classes to use in jquery..

to explain.. this is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/wUWYs/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="red row4 col1"></div>
<div class="red row3 col2"></div>
<div class="red row2 col3"></div>
<div class="red row1 col4"></div>

<div class="blue row1 col1"></div>
<div class="blue row2 col2"></div>
<div class="blue row3 col3"></div>
<div class="blue row4 col4"></div>
```

and this is what I tried to do with jquery:

**jQuery:**

```
$(".red").each(function(){
    var colNumber = $(this).attr("class");
    $(this).hover(
        function(){$(".blue."+colNumber).show();},
        function(){$(".blue").hide();}
    );
});
```

the **main problem** that I want when hover `red element` who have `col1` and `row4` classes, then the two `blue elements` will shown, who have `col1` and who have `row4` ..

problem here:

```
var colNumber = $(this).attr("class");
```

how can I define the specific class, and how to make the number variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
$(".blue").hide();
var getClass = function(target){
  return $.map(target.className
                     .split(' '), function(e){                           
                       return e == 'red' ? null : '.blue.' + e;
                    }).join(', ');
};
$(".red").hover(function(e){       
    $(getClass(e.target)).show();
 }, function(e){
    $(getClass(e.target)).hide();
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/wUWYs/4/)

The idea is simple, you just need to get the className of the hovered red div, remove the `"red"`, trim it, split by space to get array of other classes, such as `["col1", "row4"]`, then you just join it to make the string such as `".blue.col1, .blue.row4"` and use this string as the selector to select the blue divs.

Comment: Great! can you explain what you did?

Comment: @Ahmad see my update, it's simple. Also there are some other solutions but I think this is the simplest one. You may want to find more about the jQuery method `$.map()`.

Comment: @Ahmad see my updated demo, the previous demo has a bug, it works only if you specify the `red` as the first class, like in `"red col1 row1"`, if it is `"col1 red row1"`, the demo won't work. The updated demo works perfectly.

Comment: thanks @King King, I will read about `$.map()`, but I have a small relative question: If i have `div.row1`, `div.row2`, `div.row3`... and i want to select all of them, is there a shortcut to refer to variable numbers? something like `("row[*]")` maybe ?!

Comment: @Ahmad we don't have any pure CSS selector supporting that requirement, there is only a similar selector called ***attribute selector***, but I think it's not suitable in this case (you can do something like `div[class^=row]`, but it's not exact, such as it can match `div`s with `class='rowL'`. You should use the `filter` method to filter for the matched elements. Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YAdXk/22/) to understand it more. Note that I used ***RegExp*** here, it's an essential part of Javascript, you should read about it, it's very helpful in searching, filtering, replacing,...

Answer (score 2):

Use index property instead:

```
$(this).hover(
    function(){$(".blue:eq("+$(this).index()+")").show();},
    function(){$(".blue").hide();}
);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aJMUk/)**

Comment: thanx, but what i meant that when you hover red col1 row4, then two blue elements will appear: who have ".col1" and who have ".row4"

Answer (score 0):

Not use jQuery, you view this example

```
 .red.col1:hover ~ .col1{
    display:block !important;
   }
 .red.col2:hover ~ .col2{
      display:block !important;
  }
.red.col3:hover ~ .col3{
   display:block !important;
}
.red.col4:hover ~ .col4{
   display:block !important;
 }
 ![enter image description here][1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/cfeSy/

Comment: nice solution, but my original code is more complex than using only hover action, beside the main problem still exist:)

Comment: do you think my answer false

Comment: sorry, your answer is correct, but what I want is " how to define specific variable class for element have multiple classes"..
The original code in the My Page not that simple, it uses several tasks depend on this partial specifically and not just using CSS.
However, thanks for your answer again.